# Value of a unique attribute across multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

recently I have recently been working with databases and I was wondering if it was possible to have different values in multiple tables, using auto increment. I mean, I have the id attribute which is the primary key for both the bank transfer payment table and the cash payment table, I need that these two attributes never have the same values ... can this be done?

Comment: SO is English-only. Sorry, there's no Stack Overflow en Italien.

Comment: I hope, now it is understandable, sorry..